# Decrypt TLS (Diffie–Hellman) messages using Wireshark?

Tags: encryption, public-key-encryption

Is it possible to decrypt and see messages encrypted over TLS using Diffie–Hellman algorithm using Wireshark?

Comment: 1) Which DH suites are you talking about? Anonymous DH, Fixed DH, or authenticated with DHE? 2) Are you talking about an attack, or are you talking about debugging in cooperation with one of the endpoints?

Comment: No I am talking about debugging of messages between client and server . Its an Ephemeral DH

Comment: That clarification is inconsistent with you accepting Duncan's answer. His answer is about attacks by third parties, not debugging with the cooperation of an involved party. In principle it would be possible to decrypt those by having the client or server send a copy of the session key to the interceptor. Or alternatively intercepting the calls to the SSL library where the data passes through in the plain.

Comment: Oh great.Thanks for ht Info.If both the participants expose the session keys in some logs how can I decrypt the messages in wireshark using those keys?

Comment: I can see RSA key list in Edit>preferences SSL in wireshark I assume thats for RSA algorithm.Which option I have to use for DHE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Messages secured by TLS are not vulnerable to snooping attacks.

The initial exchange of key material is secured using the public keys of the participants. The subsequent exchange of data is protected by a session key known only to those participants.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.In case the participants expose those session keys also by using any debugging logs still we will not be able to decrypt those messages?

Answer (score 1):

You **can** decrypt DHE_RSA ciphersuites. I just did it here myself (https connection over a socks5-ssh tunnel).  Both tunnel and https connection under complete control of myself, mind you, i.e. you have to start the tunnel with the Wireshark trace running.

In my case I needed a more recent version than my OS's default Wireshark installation (1.10 something), so compiled 1.12.1 from source and was pleasantly surprised.

Comment: Could you give some more details on how you did this?

Comment: This requires wireshark to have access to at least one of the private keys in use for each layer of encryption. It only works without configuration because wireshark knows where most applications store their keys.